# Slow Query performance on Azure Tables when using Partition Key and ranged RowKeys

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I'm very new to Azure Tables, and i'm running into some performance problems.
I have a query, that fetches thousands of rows using a partition key and a ranged rowkey.

PartitionKey = "Example123" and RowKey >= DateTime.Now.Ticks and RowKey < DateTime.Now.AddHours(1).Ticks.
The rowkey is a guid prefixed with a datetime.Ticks string.

This query takes **2-3 seconds to return 8000 entries**. Is this reasonable?

**Example entry:**

> A: "C6-85-08-07-06-98",
>   B: "C6-85-08-07-06-i1",
>   C: 123,
>   At: "2013-12-03T19:16:26.0799718Z",
>   PartitionKey: "example1",
>   RowKey: "635216949860799718_ca86be88-0995-4da8-90d6-351c615ec9ab",
>   Timestamp: "2013-12-03T19:16:36.5872058+00:00",
>   ETag: "W/"datetime'2013-12-03T19%3A16%3A36.5872058Z'""

**Example Code**
This is the code i'm using (SDK 2.1):

```
TableQuery<RawDataEntity> rangeQuery = new TableQuery<RawDataEntity>().Where(
            TableQuery.CombineFilters(
                TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("PartitionKey", QueryComparisons.Equal, _partitionKey),
                TableOperators.And,
                IsWithin(from, to)
                ));

         // returns after ~3000 ms
         var result = _table.ExecuteQuery(rangeQuery).ToList();




// Helper method
public static string IsWithin(DateTime from, DateTime to)
    {
        return TableQuery.CombineFilters(
                TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("RowKey", QueryComparisons.GreaterThanOrEqual, from.Ticks.ToString()),
                TableOperators.And,
                TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("RowKey", QueryComparisons.LessThan, to.Ticks.ToString())

                );
    }
```

If there is nothing *wrong* with my query - what other ways are there to query a large table(easily over 10k rows) and return 10 000+ rows of data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering how the API works, 3 seconds is pretty fast. If you look at how the data is returned by the API using a tool like Fiddler, you will probably notice that your data is fetched over a few requests. The API uses paging to return your data.

I would recommend if possible that you query for subsets of your data using multiple parallel queries.

Comment: I've tried using fiddler to see the requests, but somehow they don't get captured (maybe because of some Win8 changes). Is there any good way of doing this "chunking", or should i just try to anticipate the size of my requests and do them "dumb", perhaps by splitting the from-to datespan by hour and do many request if i anticipate alot of data during that datespan? Would be interesting if i could first do a "COUNT" request in order to make smarter partial/chunking queries.

Comment: I agree that it's not an easy problem to solve. But querying for smaller time spans could do the trick where you could query for 30 mins or 1h chunks if the number of rows is inferior to 1000. If my memory isn't failing me, the cut-off used for paging is 1000 records.

Comment: Right, I guess this is the way. After doing some more calculations on how many rows this logging system will introduce, i've concluded that for each day it could reach 1 million rows. This amount of rows will take alot of time to fetch regardless, so I guess I will need to introduce some type of background process that is doing fetch/processing during the whole day and saves the processed result in another table. Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: My pleasure, if you have any questions feel free to reach out as you have done on twitter

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that the api is internally doing multiple requests to return the 3k rows. Further, since you do a .ToList() you do not get any results until all of requests have completed and the results are cached in memory. An alternative would be to execute the query segmented via the ExecuteSegmented[Async] apis. These will allow you to get result pages earlier, and if you wish specify a maxresults count to lower the total number of records returned per request.

Additionally, I would recommend upgrading the to [3.0 client lib](http://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.Storage). It has support for [JSON light / Nometadata](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2013/12/05/windows-azure-tables-introducing-json.aspx) which can reduce payloads by up to ~70% depending on the scenario. This will dramatically reduce IO and CPU usage required to parse these query results which should help improve the latencies of these queries.

Hope this helps.